# How to do paging in JSOM which is using KQL Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, jsom, kql

I want to do optimized paging in JSOM which is using KQL Query. Any help and reference will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried appending &startrow=11&rowlimit=10 to your query in addition to your querytext?

Comment: Yes but is there any option to get last position of the listitemCollection?